# In scala, how do you instantiate a class from different inputs?

Tags: scala

For example, in C++ I can do something like:

```
class  x {
     int _a;
     int _b;
     int _c;
    public:
       x(int a, int b, int c) { _a = a; _b = b; _c = c; }
       x(y& other) {
                   sometype z = deserialize(y)
                   // ...do some magic
                   _a = z.a; _b = z.b; _c = z.c;
       }

}
```

so I can instantiate (x) from discrete parameters (3 ints), or define a constructor where I accept an instance of (y), deserialize it, and extract the data from it.

in scala I'd wish to have this, which doesn't work since I cannot have something else before calling the main constructor

```
case class x (int a, int b, int c) { 
   def this(from:y ) { 
   val z = deserialize(x);  // this will fail
   // do some magic; 
   this(z.a, z.b, z.c)}
}
```

I can take the alternate constructor logic and externalize it to be done by a helper before creating the object, but I'd like to preserve encapsulation if at all possible.

Are there better patterns for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add your own `apply` method inside the companion object.

Here is a simple example, where the `a`, `b`, `c` are read from a string.

```
case class x (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)

object x {
  def apply(s: String): x = {
    val ints = s.split(",")
    x(ints(0).toInt, ints(1).toInt, ints(2).toInt)
  }
}
```

Then calling `x("1,2,3")` will give you `x(1,2,3)`.

Comment: Thank you. I need to do more reading on companion objects, I guess, I didn't think of it right off hand. Scala makes so many things simple, and yet some things feel cumbersome.